# How do install C header files in Mac OSX Sierra?

Tags: c, gcc

I have missing header files like `malloc.h` and `conio.h` in my MAC.

How do I install it?

> gcc linkedlistmenu.c
> linkedlistmenu.c:2:19: fatal error: malloc.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Have you tried `stdlib.h` instead?

Comment: neither of those headers are part of the C standard

Comment: Did you cross-check with a good C book? Don't learn C from obscure youtube videos or online tutorials!

Comment: conio.h is much more something related to Windows env., don't even try to use such on MacOS. Use standard headers and your code will be much more portable.

Comment: Search the header files with `find /usr/include -name "malloc.h`. If everthing is right the include directory should be: `-I/usr/include/sys"`.

Comment: @AndreKampling Actually, on Sierra and later `/usr/include` no longer exists. On those you'll have to use `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include`.

Comment: Please note that `malloc` and friends are to be found in `stdlib.h`.

Comment: Thanks to all... am just new to MAC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, `malloc.h` is deprecated (and not available on your system).  Instead, you should be using `stdlib.h`.  Furthermore, `conio.h` is an implementation specific header - and in this case, it is Windows and MS-DOS specific.  It is not available on MacOS.  Both of these are non-standard headers, and therefore are not preferred due to issues with portability.  [`ncurses`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) (which should already be available on MacOS) provides similar functionality to `conio.h`; see if that has what you're looking for.

However, your best shot if you *really* need these header files is to install a virtualization program such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org), install Windows, and work from there.

Comment: Thank you very much... it was really helpful... new to MAC here.

Comment: @ArunKumar Glad the clarification helped :)

Comment: stdlib.h includes malloc.h? What's the problem with including malloc.h directly?